# Select only one row from a MySQL table where value is an array?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select the record of a single customer, let's say a customer whose id is 2 from the table named giftcards. In giftcards the id of customers is store in JSON format (column = customerid). How can I do this? I'm working with PHP.

[image]

Gifcards table structure is shown here

Comment: Don't do that. You should have a table that maps `gcid` to `customerid`s.

Comment: you have a json so you need to use them or normalize the tables

Comment: It's possible with new MySql version, but not efficient. Also there should be indexes on `customerid` to link faster to customers. In small database you will see no big difference, but if it grows - maintenance and speed will be your pain in the _back_

Comment: You might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad for saving complex data into one column